# In Python, when is platlib != purelib?

Tags: python, setuptools

Python has the ability to install `platlib` and `purelib` in different locations. What's the difference, why does this feature exist, and when is it used in practice?

Comment: you can install platlib or purelib in anything location as you like, python will check out the 
PYTHONPATH environment var, and ~/.pythonstartup profile file etc when python start process. python moduel system depends on PYTHONPATH, site.py etc.

Answer (score 5):

On 64-bit Red Hat-based platforms `platlib` and `purelib` are different. Here's the values for CentOS 7:

```
    'purelib': '$base/lib/python$py_version_short/site-packages',
    'platlib': '$platbase/lib64/python$py_version_short/site-packages',
```

This allows the binary extensions to follow the system convention of putting 64-bit binaries in a lib64 directory while the architecture independent files are places in a lib directory.

Answer (score 4):

To quote from [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html):

> for example, if you want to maintain all Python module-related files under python in your home directory, and you want a separate directory for each platform that you use your home directory from[.]

(I.e., you're in a heterogeneous network environment where computers may run different operating systems but each mounts your homedir from a network storage server.)

Comment: I know platlib /can/ != purelib, but is it really done in practice?